# How to write the test for useSelector with Jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I'm new to testing and very confused on what I need to do to thoroughly test my `MealsSummary.tsx` component. I want to start with testing if my component is retrieving `items` from the redux `store` correctly. I found a couple answers from SO to setup my mock function, though I'm unsure if the setup is correct. If it is, what should I do next in terms of testing my 'useSelector' mock function. Ty in advance

`MealsSummary.test.tsx`

```
describe('mock ', () => {
    jest.mock("react-redux", () =>({ 
        ...jest.requireActual("react-redux"),
        useSelector: jest.fn()
    }))
    describe("testing useselector", () => {
        const mockedState = {
            user: {
                image: 'null',
                name: 'testing', 
                id: 'name+date',
                calories: 2000,
                proteins: 150,
                carbohydrates: 200, 
                fats: 90, 
            },
        };
        test('get items', () =>{
            //not sure what to write
        })
    });
})
```

`MealsSummary.tsx`

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { RootState } from "../../redux/store";
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text} from "react-native"
import { MealCard } from './MealCard'

export const MealsSummary = (): JSX.Element => {
    const { items } = useSelector((store: RootState) => store.nutrition)
    let title: string = 'Food'
    return (<>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
            <ScrollView >
                {items.map(item => (
                    <MealCard item={item} key={item.id}/>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
    </>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** mock `useSelector` of the `react-redux` package, you will break its function. Instead, we should create a store with `createStore` API of `redux` and pass the store to the `Provider` component. We could create the mock state when create the redux store.

E.g.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { createStore } from "redux";

type RootState = {
  nutrition: {
    items: any[]
  }
};
export const MealsSummary = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { items } = useSelector((store: RootState) => store.nutrition);
  console.log('items: ', items);
  return <div />
}

describe("74765250", () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const store = createStore((state = { nutrition: { items: [1, 2, 3] } }) => state)
    render(<Provider store={store}><MealsSummary /></Provider>)
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74765250/index.test.tsx (13.661 s)
  74765250
    ✓ should pass (36 ms)

  console.log
    items:  [ 1, 2, 3 ]

      at MealsSummary (stackoverflow/74765250/index.test.tsx:13:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.37 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

More test cases, see [useSelector.spec.tsx](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v8.0.5/test/hooks/useSelector.spec.tsx#L108) file